# How to call method in Kinect SDK?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a program that checks if the Kinect is connected to the computer. However, I don't really know if I need to call a method (I would assume so) and where? I've attached the code that I got from an introductory Kinect book. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Kinect;

namespace test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

    KinectSensor kinectSensor;
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += Kinects_StatusChanged;
            foreach (KinectSensor kinect in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
            {
                if (kinect.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
                {
                    kinectSensor = kinect;
                    MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("No Kinect Found");
            else
                Initialize();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void Kinects_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case KinectStatus.Connected:
                if (kinectSensor == null)
                {
                    kinectSensor = e.Sensor;
                    Initialize();
                }
                break;
            case KinectStatus.Disconnected:
                if (kinectSensor == e.Sensor)
                {
                    Clean();
                    MessageBox.Show("Kinect was disconnected");
                }
                break;
            case KinectStatus.NotReady:
                break;
            case KinectStatus.NotPowered:
                if (kinectSensor == e.Sensor)
                {
                    Clean();
                    MessageBox.Show("Kinect is not powered anymore.");
                }
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Unhandled Status: " + e.Status);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        if (kinectSensor == null)
            return;
        kinectSensor.Start();
    }

    private void Clean()
    {
        if (kinectSensor != null)
        {
            kinectSensor.Stop();
            kinectSensor = null;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Download the [Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx).  There are multiple examples in there on how to do multiple things, that will get you started and help you understand how to talk to the Kinect.

Once you've connected to the Kinect you need to set it up and then subscribe to the event callbacks.  You'll end up with a function that looks something like this:

```
private void InitializeKinectServices(KinectSensorManager kinectSensorManager, KinectSensor sensor)
{
    // configure the color stream
    kinectSensorManager.ColorFormat = ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30;
    kinectSensorManager.ColorStreamEnabled = true;

    // configure the depth stream
    kinectSensorManager.DepthStreamEnabled = true;

    kinectSensorManager.TransformSmoothParameters =
        new TransformSmoothParameters
        {
            // as the smoothing value is increased responsiveness to the raw data
            // decreases; therefore, increased smoothing leads to increased latency.
            Smoothing = 0.5f,
            // higher value corrects toward the raw data more quickly,
            // a lower value corrects more slowly and appears smoother.
            Correction = 0.5f,
            // number of frames to predict into the future.
            Prediction = 0.5f,
            // determines how aggressively to remove jitter from the raw data.
            JitterRadius = 0.05f,
            // maximum radius (in meters) that filtered positions can deviate from raw data.
            MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f
        };

    // configure the skeleton stream
    sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += OnSkeletonFrameReady;
    kinectSensorManager.SkeletonStreamEnabled = true;

    // initialize the gesture recognizer
    _gestureController = new GestureController();
    _gestureController.GestureRecognized += OnGestureRecognized;

    kinectSensorManager.KinectSensorEnabled = true;

    if (!kinectSensorManager.KinectSensorAppConflict)
    {
      // additional init
    }
}
```

This is my generic setup function, which is based off of examples from the Developer Toolkit.  You will not be able to just plug this into your code and it will work.  Having a look at the examples in the Toolkit will give you an understanding of where this happens and how to best manage it.

The `KinectExplorer` example is a good overall project to look over.  It will also give you a clear understanding of how the function above works (it has the same function).